# How to read data from Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web application.

SysAdmin of some organization logs in to my web application and need to be able to load the emails of users in his organization into the application.

SysAdmin manage his organization's users in Azure AD.

Where can I find the step by step procedure for such integration?

I understand that I need to create an app in Azure marketplace and SysAdmin need to give access permissions for my app. Just can't find the exact steps how this should be done end to end.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to use Microsoft Graph API. Please use this link to get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts.

Comment: @GauravMantri,
Thanks, and if I also need to access calendar events of the people inside organization, is it the same flow or is there a more simple way? (once I have the email addresses)

Comment: You can access calendar events by granting calenders.read api permission and by using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/UserId/calendar/events`

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that I need to create an app in Azure marketplace and SysAdmin need to give access permissions for my app. Just can't find the exact steps how this should be done end to end.

You need to create an ***Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)*** application in your tenant:

[image]

And grant **`User.Read.All`** delegated API permission:

[image]

Make sure to **grant tenant wide admin consent** to the API permissions by signing with another tenant Admin user:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientIDofApp
```

[image]

The **Enterprise Application** in the other tenant now have API permissions granted (*if this is not granted then **403** error will occur*):

[image]

I used the below endpoint to **authorize other organization users**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=User.Read.All
&state=12345
```

I logged in with **admin user of other organization**:

[image]

The **auth-code** got generated successfully:

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:User.Read.All
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the details are displayed:

[image]

**To fetch emails of the users in the admins/other organization**, use the below query by passing the above access token:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=mail
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)